# Sqlite insert gives syntax error

Tags: sqlite, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am working on flex actionscript project. In which i am going to save/insert records in `sqlite` database, which i got in response.

But, form that records some records are not inserted into table. When i catch the error it gives sql error.

> near '/': syntax error

In response i have got whole html markup.

I have written/execute query inside `for loop` like:

```
var insert:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement(); 
insert.sqlConnection = sqlConnectionSync;
insert.text = 'INSERT OR IGNORE INTO TableName (MessageID, AccountID, Body) VALUES ("' + listArray[i].MessageID + '","' + listArray[i].AccountID + '","' + listArray[i].Body + '")';
insert.execute();
```

I have also tried changing `"` in place of `'` and vice versa.

But it gives other error of `'`

> Error #3115: SQL Error.
>
> near 'll': syntax error

And

> near '_blank': syntax error

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid such problem, you can use [`SQLStatement.parameters`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/SQLStatement.html#parameters) property like this, for example :

```
var insert:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement(); 

    insert.text = 'INSERT OR IGNORE INTO TableName (MessageID, AccountID, Body) VALUES (:param1, :param2, :param3)';

    insert.parameters[':param1'] = listArray[i].MessageID;
    insert.parameters[':param2'] = listArray[i].AccountID;
    insert.parameters[':param3'] = listArray[i].Body;

    insert.execute();
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Can you give me solution of this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37725499/datagrid-itemrenderer-getting-issue-while-scroll

Answer (score 0):

Posting the full query as text would help but most likely you have  "  or  '  characters in your data (like ...="_blank" or "You'll"). You'd need to escape your variable values before inserting them into the database. I have switched " and ' from your example:

```
insert.text = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO TableName (MessageID, AccountID, Body) VALUES ('" + escapeChars(listArray[i].MessageID) + "','" + escapeChars(listArray[i].AccountID) + "','" + escapeChars(listArray[i].Body) + "')";

private function escapeChars(myString:String):String
{
   // Since we are using "'" we'd need to escape all other "'" characters
   return myString.replace(/'/gi, "\'");
}
```